# Move data into 3 Separate Hashes inside loop in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

It's only my second post and I'm still learning ruby. 
I'm trying to figure this out based on my Java knowledge but I can't seem to get it right.

What I need to do is: 
I have a function that reads a file line by line and extract different car features from each line, for example:

```
def convertListings2Catalogue (fileName)

f = File.open(fileName, "r")
f.each_line do |line|

  km=line[/[0-9]+km/]
  t = line[(Regexp.union(/sedan/i, /coupe/i, /hatchback/i, /station/i, /suv/i))]
  trans = ....
end end
```

> Now for each line I need to store the extracted features into separate
>   hashes that I can access later in my program.
>
> The issues I'm facing: 
>   1) I'm overwriting the features in the same hash
>   2) Can't access the hash outside my function

That what's in my file:

> 65101km,Sedan,Manual,2010,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,camry,SE,{AC,
>   Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry}
>
> coupe,1100km,auto,RWD, Mercedec,CLK,LX ,18FO724A,2017,{AC, Heated
>   Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry, Power seats},6L/100km,Used
>
> AWD,SUV,0km,auto,new,Honda,CRV,8L/100km,{Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors,
>   Keyless Entry},19BF723A,2018,LE

Now my function extracts the features of each car model, but I need to store these features in 3 different hashes with the same keys but different values.

```
listing = Hash.new(0)
  listing = { kilometers: km, type: t, transmission: trans, drivetrain: dt, status: status, car_maker: car_maker }
```

I tried moving the data from one hash to another, I even tried storing the data in an array first and then moving it to the hash but I still can't figure out how to create separate hashes inside a loop.
**Thanks**

Comment: Can you add an example of the expected or preferred output?

Comment: Yeah of course!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question but I thought it was important to suggest how you might deal with a more fundamental issue: extracting the desired information from each line of the file in an effective and Ruby-like manner. Once you have that information, in the form of an array of hashes, one hash per line, you can do with it what you want. Alternatively, you could loop through the lines in the file, constructing a hash for each line and performing any desired operations before going on to the next line.

Being new to Ruby you will undoubtedly find some of the code below difficult to understand. If you persevere, however, I think you will be able to understand all of it, and in the process learn a lot about Ruby. I've made some suggestions in the last section of my answer to help you decipher the code.

**Code**

```
words_by_key = {
  type:         %w| sedan coupe hatchback station suv |,
  transmission: %w| auto manual steptronic |,
  drivetrain:   %w| fwd rwd awd |,
  status:       %w| used new |,
  car_maker:    %w| honda toyota mercedes bmw lexus |,
  model:        %w| camry clk crv |
}
  #=> {:type=>["sedan", "coupe", "hatchback", "station", "suv"],
  #    :transmission=>["auto", "manual", "steptronic"],
  #    :drivetrain=>["fwd", "rwd", "awd"],
  #    :status=>["used", "new"],
  #    :car_maker=>["honda", "toyota", "mercedes", "bmw", "lexus"],
  #    :model=>["camry", "clk", "crv"]}

WORDS_TO_KEYS = words_by_key.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| v.each { |s| h[s] = k } }
  #=> {"sedan"=>:type, "coupe"=>:type, "hatchback"=>:type, "station"=>:type, "suv"=>:type,
  #    "auto"=>:transmission, "manual"=>:transmission, "steptronic"=>:transmission,
  #    "fwd"=>:drivetrain, "rwd"=>:drivetrain, "awd"=>:drivetrain,
  #    "used"=>:status, "new"=>:status,
  #    "honda"=>:car_maker, "toyota"=>:car_maker, "mercedes"=>:car_maker,
  #      "bmw"=>:car_maker, "lexus"=>:car_maker,
  #    "camry"=>:model, "clk"=>:model, "crv"=>:model}
```

```
module ExtractionMethods
  def km(str)
    str[/\A\d+(?=km\z)/]
  end

  def year(str)
    str[/\A\d+{4}\z/]
  end

  def stock(str)
    return nil if str.end_with?('km')
    str[/\A\d+\p{Alpha}\p{Alnum}*\z/]
  end

  def trim(str)
    str[/\A\p{Alpha}{2}\z/]
  end

  def fuel_consumption(str)
    str.to_f if str[/\A\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=l\/100km\z)/]
  end
end
```

```
class K
  include ExtractionMethods      
  def extract_hashes(fname)
    File.foreach(fname).with_object([]) do |line, arr|
      line = line.downcase
      idx_left = line.index('{')
      idx_right = line.index('}')
      if idx_left && idx_right    
        g = { set_of_features: line[idx_left..idx_right] }
        line[idx_left..idx_right] = ''
        line.squeeze!(',')
      else
        g = {}
      end
      arr << line.split(',').each_with_object(g) do |word, h|
        word.strip!
        if WORDS_TO_KEYS.key?(word)
          h[WORDS_TO_KEYS[word]] = word
        else
          ExtractionMethods.instance_methods.find do |m|
            v = public_send(m, word)
            (h[m] = v) unless v.nil?
            v
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
data =<<BITTER_END
65101km,Sedan,Manual,2010,18131A,FWD,Used,5.5L/100km,Toyota,camry,SE,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry}
coupe,1100km,auto,RWD, Mercedec,CLK,LX ,18FO724A,2017,{AC, Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry, Power seats},6L/100km,Used
AWD,SUV,0km,auto,new,Honda,CRV,8L/100km,{Heated Seats, Heated Mirrors, Keyless Entry},19BF723A,2018,LE
BITTER_END
```

```
FILE_NAME = 'temp'
File.write(FILE_NAME, data)
  #=> 353 (characters written to file)

k = K.new
  #=> #<K:0x00000001c257d348>
k.extract_hashes(FILE_NAME)
  #=> [{:set_of_features=>"{ac, heated seats, heated mirrors, keyless entry}",
  #     :km=>"65101", :type=>"sedan", :transmission=>"manual", :year=>"2010",
  #     :stock=>"18131a", :drivetrain=>"fwd", :status=>"used", :fuel_consumption=>5.5,
  #     :car_maker=>"toyota", :model=>"camry", :trim=>"se"},
  #    {:set_of_features=>"{ac, heated seats, heated mirrors, keyless entry, power seats}",
  #     :type=>"coupe", :km=>"1100", :transmission=>"auto", :drivetrain=>"rwd",
  #     :model=>"clk", :trim=>"lx", :stock=>"18fo724a", :year=>"2017",
  #     :fuel_consumption=>6.0, :status=>"used"},
  #    {:set_of_features=>"{heated seats, heated mirrors, keyless entry}",
  #     :drivetrain=>"awd", :type=>"suv", :km=>"0", :transmission=>"auto",
  #     :status=>"new", :car_maker=>"honda", :model=>"crv", :fuel_consumption=>8.0,
  #     :stock=>"19bf723a", :year=>"2018", :trim=>"le"}]
```

**Explanation**

Firstly, note that the HEREDOC needs to be un-indented before being executed.

You will see that the instance method `K#extract_hashes` uses [IO#foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach) to read the file line-by-line.<sup>1</sup>

The first step in processing each line of the file is to downcase it. You will then want to split the string on commas to form an array of words. There is a problem, however, in that you don't want to split on commas that are between a left and right brace (`{` and `}`), which corresponds to the key `:set_of_features`. I decided to deal with that by determining the indices of the two braces, creating a hash with the single key `:set_of_features`, delete that substring from the line and lastly replace a resulting pair of adjacent commas with a single comma:

```
  idx_left = line.index('{')
  idx_right = line.index('}')
  if idx_left && idx_right    
    g = { set_of_features: line[idx_left..idx_right] }
    line[idx_left..idx_right] = ''
    line.squeeze!(',')
  else
    g = {}
  end
```

See [String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html) for the documentation of the `String` methods used here and elsewhere.

We can now convert the resulting `line` to an array of words by splitting on the commas. If any capitalization is desired in the output this should be done after the hashes have been constructed.

We will build on the hash `{ set_of_features: line[idx_left..idx_right] }` just created. When complete, it will be appended to the array being returned.

Each element (`word`) in the array, is then processed. If it is a key of the hash `WORDS_TO_KEYS` we set

```
h[WORDS_TO_KEYS[word]] = word
```

and are finished with that word. If not, we execute each of the instance methods `m` in the module `ExtractionMethods` until one is found for which `m[word]` is not `nil`. When that is found another key-value pair is added to the hash `h`:

```
h[m] = word
```

Notice that the name of each instance method in `ExtractionMethods`, which is a symbol (e.g., `:km`), is a key in the hash `h`. Having separate methods facilitates debugging and testing.

I could have written:

```
if    (s = km(word))
  s
elsif (s = year(word))
  s
elsif (s = stock(str))
  s
elsif (s = trim(str))
  s
elsif (s = fuel_consumption(str))
  s
end
```

but since all these methods take the same argument, `word`, we can instead use [Object#public_send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Object.html#method-i-public_send):

```
a = [:km, :year, :stock, :trim, :fuel_consumption]

a.find do |m|
  v = public_send(m, word)
  (h[m] = v) unless v.nil?
  v 
end
```

A final tweak is to put all the methods in the array `a` in a module `ExtractionMethods` and include that module in the class `K`. We can then replace `a` in the `find` expression above with `ExtractionMethods.instance_methods`. (See [Module#instance_methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods).)

Suppose now that the data are changed so that additional fields are added (e.g., for "colour" or "price"). Then the *only* modifications to the code required are changes to `words_by_key` and/or the addition of methods to `ExtractionMethods`.

**Understanding the code**

It may be helpful to run the code with `puts` statements inserted. For example,

```
idx_left = line.index('{')
idx_right = line.index('}')
puts "idx_left=#{idx_left}, idx_left=#{idx_left}"
```

Where code is *chained* it may be helpful to break it up with temporary variables and insert `puts` statements. For example, change

```
arr << line.split(',').each_with_object(g) do |word, h|
  ...
```

to

```
a = line.split(',')
puts "line.split(',')=#{a}"
enum = a.each_with_object(g)
puts "enum.to_a=#{enum.to_a}"
arr << enum do |word, h|
  ...
```

The second `puts` here is merely to see what elements the enumerator `enum` will generate and pass to the block.

Another way of doing that is to use the handy method [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-tap), which is inserted between two methods:

```
arr << line.split(',').tap { |a| puts "line.split(',')=#{a}"}.
            each_with_object(g) do |word, h|
              ...
```

`tap` (great name, eh?), as used here, simply returns its receiver after displaying its value.

Lastly, I've used the method [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) in a couple of places. It may seem complex but it's actually quite simple. For example,

```
arr << line.split(',').each_with_object(g) do |word, h|
  ...
end
```

is effectively equivalent to:

```
h = g
arr << line.split(',').each do |word|
  ...
end
h
```

<sup>1 Many [IO](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html) methods are typically invoked on [File](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html). This is acceptable because `File.superclass #=> IO`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed answer, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the fact that your file instance is an [enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html). This allows you to leverage the [`inject`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) method, and you can seed that with an empty hash. `collector` in this case is the hash that gets passed along as the iteration continues. Be sure to (implicitly, by having `collector` be the last line of the block) return the value of collector as the `inject` method will use this to feed into the next iteration. It's some pretty powerful stuff!

I *think* this is roughly what you're going for. I used `model` as the key in the hash, and `set_of_features` as your data.

```
def convertListings2Catalogue (fileName)
  f = File.open(fileName, "r")

  my_hash = f.inject({}) do |collector, line|
    km=line[/[0-9]+km/]
    t = line[(Regexp.union(/sedan/i, /coupe/i, /hatchback/i, /station/i, /suv/i))]
    trans = line[(Regexp.union(/auto/i, /manual/i, /steptronic/i))]
    dt = line[(Regexp.union(/fwd/i, /rwd/i, /awd/i))]
    status = line[(Regexp.union(/used/i, /new/i))]
    car_maker = line[(Regexp.union(/honda/i, /toyota/i, /mercedes/i, /bmw/i, /lexus/i))]  
    stock = line.scan(/(\d+[a-z0-9]+[a-z](?<!km\b))(?:,|$)/i).first
    year = line.scan(/(\d{4}(?<!km\b))(?:,|$)/).first
    trim = line.scan(/\b[a-zA-Z]{2}\b/).first
    fuel = line.scan(/[\d.]+L\/\d*km/).first
    set_of_features = line.scan(/\{(.*?)\}/).first
    model = line[(Regexp.union(/camry/i, /clk/i, /crv/i))]
    collector[model] = set_of_features
    collector
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, will this create separate hashes ? In my case I need 3 hashes all with the same keys but different values

Comment: @SaraMoufarrej Ah, so you want an array of hashes, where all the values for each hash are constructed in each iteration of the loop? So, in other words, one hash for each line?

Comment: Yes, that's it exactly!